# doing algebra with an MxNx3 array using vectorization in python?

Tags: arrays, vector, scipy, vectorization, linear-algebra

Suppose I have an MxNx3 array A, where the first two indexes refer to the coordinates a point, and the last index (the number '3') refers to the three components of a vector. e.g. A[4,7,:] = [1,2,3] means that the vector at point (7,4) is (1,2,3).

Now I need to implement the following operations:

```
Lx = D*ux - (x-xo)  
Ly = D*uy + (y-yo)  
Lz = D
```

where D, ux, uy, xo, yo are all constants that are already known. Lx, Ly and Lz are the three components of the vector at each point (x,y) (note: x is the column index and y is the row index respectively). The biggest problem is about the x-xo and y-yo, as x and y  are different for different points. So how to carry out these operations for an MxNx3 array efficiently, using vectorized code or some other fast methods?

thanks

Comment: Did you consider expanding the matrix for MxNx5, so that you explicitly include X and Y values in the matrix instead of just getting the values from the indices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `meshgrid` function from numpy:

```
import numpy as np
M=10
N=10
D=1
ux=0.5
uy=0.5
xo=1
yo=1
A=np.empty((M,N,3))
x=range(M)
y=range(N)
xv, yv = np.meshgrid(x, y, sparse=False, indexing='ij')
A[:,:,0]=D*ux - (xv-xo)
A[:,:,1]=D*uy - (yv-yo) 
A[:,:,2]=D
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to operate on the X and Y values, you should include them in the matrix (or in other matrix) instead of relying in their indexes.

For that, you could use some of [range creation routines](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.array-creation.html#numerical-ranges) from Numpy, specially `numpy.mgrid`.